# Computing the histogram of an image in Parallel

Tags: image-processing, mpi, parallel-processing

How can I calculate the histogram of an image using parallel Computing? Histogram of an image in serial is easy, but I don't have any idea about calculating it in Parallel.

Any idea, algorithm, source code or a helpful link would be appreciated.

I am using MPI.

Comment: what have you tried? have you done any parallel programming in the past? do you know histograms? this is not a tutorial site, but a site for specific questions that can be given exact answers. see the FAQ.

Comment: @phresnel You wouldn't want him to give anything he's tried. That might taint possible answers; people might suggest improvements to his existing techniques, rather than providing the best answer outright.

Comment: @IanBoyd: But what shall we recommend? An algorithm? A book about parallel programming? Parallel architecture? Locking patterns or other synchronization techniques? Big integers? Suitable programming languages? Source code of a full application for free?

Comment: @phresnel recommend *anything*. The best answer will receive the most upvotes, and likely accepted.

Comment: @IanBoyd: What about http://stackoverflow.com/faq? Each of the stuffs I mentioned was answered here already.

Comment: If you find something on the [that page](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) that answers Ruhi's question, then add it as an answer. If it is a good answer it will be upvoted.

Comment: @IanBoyd: (You forgot to notify me.) Don't know what you want to tell me. The question is not in good SO- and FAQ-compliant format. If this is annoying you, then SO might not be for you or you could protest at meta.

Comment: @IanBoyd: And to reiterate: Each of [algorithm, book, architecture, locking patterns and other synchronization techniques, big nums, programming languages, source code] was already tangled on stack-overflow and therefore this question might a big dupe and definitely is too vague.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the idea:

First you scatter the image rowwise (if you program in C) or columnwise (if you program in Fortran) using `MPI_Scatter()` or `MPI_Scatterv()` (with scatterv you can distribute the image to a number of processes that is not an integer divisor of the number of rows/columns).

Then every process computes the histogram of its part of the image. Let the histogram be stored in an integer array `local_histogram` of 256 elements (I assume the images are grayscale).

At the last step a global reduction with summation is performed with `MPI_Reduce()`:

```
MPI_Reduce(local_histogram, histogram, 256, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Afterwards the full global histogram would be in the `histogram` array at process with rank 0.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I can only guess what exactöy you are looking for. Let me give you the brief outline of an algorithm for you:</sub>

Each node computes a histogram. In the final step, all of them are reduced by adding them together. The final summation could be split again, and again and again, depending on the workload.

This approach is similar to [map/reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_reduce).